# Problema con API Twilio WhatsApp con PHP

Tags: php, php7, whatsapp, twilio

Instala la dependencia de Twilio con composer, tengo la versión 7.2.0
Tengo un problema con la API de Twilio para enviar WhatsApps, me notifica error en línea 15:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' in D:\xampp\htdocs\TW\send_message.php on line 15
```

Les muestro el código:

```
<?php
    declare(strict_types = 1);
    require('vendor/autoload.php');

    $sid = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
    $token = getenv('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');

    $numeroTwilio = '+521XXXXXXXXXX';
    $numeroDestino = getenv('+521XXXXXXXXXX');

    $mensaje = 'WH de prueba';

    $client = new Twilio\Rest\Client($sid, $token);

    $client -> messages -> create(to:$numeroDestino, options:[
        'from' => $numeroTwilio,
        'body' => $mensaje
    ]);

    echo 'Mensaje enviado';
```

Obviamente por seguridad oculte datos confidenciales, pero en desarrollo coloco lo que debe ser, cabe mencionar que no estoy dentro de un trial, también menciono que tengo el codigo en localhost con XAMPP y mi versión de PHP es 7.3.26 y Zend Engine 3.3.26

Estuve revisando el siguiente vídeo tutorial en [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VMtWAphzkdg&list=PLBBj3ZYeBqPdBjidt2liMlwSuabsIic9R&index=2&t=130s&ab_channel=Twilio)